# Google Cloud Spanner scripting similar to PL/SQL or T-SQL?

Tags: scripting, google-cloud-spanner

New to Google Cloud Spanner. I am in a "research" role, not development. Is there a way to execute scripts with Cloud Spanner similar to PL/SQL or T-SQL?

I am currently using DBeaver Community to connect and execute SQL statements. Would like to be able to execute additional statements based on the result set(s) of a previously executed statement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1 - GoogleSQL Dialect Databases

This open source project will give you an interactive command line tool for Google Cloud Spanner databases: https://github.com/cloudspannerecosystem/spanner-cli

#### Option 2 - PostgreSQL Dialect Databases

Cloud Spanner also supports databases that use the [PostgreSQL dialect](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/postgresql-interface#choose). You can use `psql` with Cloud Spanner databases that are created with the PostgreSQL dialect: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/pgadapter